# UIImageView.image is nil after being set with non-nil value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, mpmediaitem

I am setting an imageView with a MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork. The code works well when I change tracks however when I leave the view and return, this code is called and the UIImageView.Image remains nil even though I am setting it with a non nil value.

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
if (artwork != nil) {
    self.songImageView.image = [artwork imageWithSize:self.songImageView.frame.size];
}
```

I have tried a couple of checks to determine that nowPlayingItem is not nil, artwork is not nil and also self.songImageView is not nil.

Any ideas where else I should be looking?

Comment: I should note this behavior. When I set a breakpoint on self.songImageView.image = 
I tried this: 

     po self.songImageView.frame.size
    error: property 'frame' not found on object of type 'UIImageView *'
    error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: According to your comment, it looks like the Imageview has no frame. Try setting the frame of the imageview first, then adding the image in the way you did

Comment: Unrelated, but note also that nil evaluates to false in Objective-C.  You could write "if (artwork) { ... }" in place of "if (artwork != nil) { ... }".

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

// now get UIImage object from the MPMediaItemArtwork object
if (artwork) {
    artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (30, 30)];
     //or
     //artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: self.songImageView.bounds.size]];

self.songImageView.image = artworkImage
}
```

Comment: I tried:

     MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
     if (artwork) {
        UIImage* artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: self.songImageView.bounds.size];
        self.songImageView.image = artworkImage;
    }


Did not work

Comment: what about using **CGSizeMake (30, 30)** ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you mentioned:

> self.songImageView.frame.size error: property 'frame' not found on
>   object of type 'UIImageView *' error: 1 errors parsing expression

It looks like self.songImageView.frame is nil.
So you may be giving it a real image but the imageview has no frame to present that image to you. So when you call imageWithSize its giving you an image with no size.

try:

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
if (artwork != nil) {
    self.songImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); // give the imageview a frame
    self.songImageView.image = [artwork imageWithSize:self.songImageView.frame.size];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem before，where I wrote the right code but when executed, it seemed that the object did not exist.

In my case, I solved the problem by adding

```
self.myObject = [[ClassOfMyObject alloc] init];
```

before I used `self.myObject`.  (Actually I added this in `ViewDidLoad` method.)

Hope my solution would help you.